# Error parsing time-zone with Time::Piece

Tags: perl

Executing a simple Perl script

```
use Time::Piece;
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime('08:00 PM AST', "%I:%M %p %Z");
```

I got the following error: **Error parsing time at /usr/local/lib/perl5/Time/Piece.pm line 469.**

Is this a bug in the library or there is something wrong with the above code? When I remove `AST` time-zone from the input string, it works, but when time-zone is left, it fails.

I don't know what exact time-zone will be in input string, so I cannot adjust that part on my end. AST *(see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_Time_Zone))* is a proper abbreviation for *Atlantic Time Zone*, so it should work. But it does not!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
use Date::Parse;
my $t = str2time('08:00 PM AST');
```

Comment: That's fine if it does what you need. But you will get Unix time values instead of `Time::Piece` objects, and it will get a substantial number of the world's time zones wrong.

Answer (score 8):

The time zone field is ambiguous and cannot be parsed. For instance, CST is the abbreviation for China Standard Time, Central Standard Time, and Cuba Standard Time.

The [module documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time%3a%3aPiece) says that the `strptime` method is from FreeBSD, where the `%Z` format accepts either the local time zone or `GMT` and nothing else. This may be true of `strptime`, but I can confirm only that, where I am located, `GMT` is acceptable while `UTC` and `AST` are not.

The solution I would recommend is to preprocess your time strings, replacing the time zone abbreviation with an unambiguous time zone offset. For instance `AST` (assuming you meant Atlantic Standard Time and not Arabia Standard Time) would be replaced with `-0400`, since it is four hours behind UTC. Then you can parse it with a `%z` format specifier and get the correct result.

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Comment: `Time::Piece->strptime("...", "...%Z")` accepts only [`GMT`](https://github.com/Dual-Life/Time-Piece/blob/1.3401/Piece.xs#L826) (the variable name is misleading). `localtime->strptime("...", "...%Z")` ignores the time zone. More on it [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/4aa50308bab6bb41c5c8dd8ebdc7defb), and probably [here](https://github.com/Dual-Life/Time-Piece/issues/52#issuecomment-1246310525).