# Look up time zone from latitude and longitude using Perl

Tags: perl, timezone, coordinates

I'm looking for a way to use Perl to get the time zone corresponding to a given latitude and longitude. Any program that runs on Linux would be okay too.

I have pictures with time in UTC and GPS coordinates and I want to use them on a website with the local time and date.

I found the [`Geo::Location::TimeZone`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Geo%3a%3aLocation%3a%3aTimeZone) module on CPAN which looks like it could do the job, but it doesn't work and I'm still trying to figure out why.

Comment: Timezones are changing all the time. While any algorithm will be right for a large percentage of coordinates, there will _always_ be places in the world where the database mapping location to timezone will be out of date and thus incorrect.

Comment: Time zone abbreviations are ambiguous (as described [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/)), so the only accurate representation of a location's time zone is its longitude. Take a look at my answer to a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21104727/622310)

Comment: I have read your question more carefully, and I'm a little confused. So you have a JPEG of the Grand Canyon at *36.1° N, 112.1° W* taken at 18:00 local time, and you want to post it on an international site that would show in, say, England, a time of 01:00?

Comment: I set all my cameras to UTC (because I'm traveling and that way I won't forget to change the timezone and my GPS device logs UTC time).
I tag my images with the logs from the GPS and then I want to put them on my website, but with the actual local-time (so that the sunset will not be show as midnight).
So: I got pictures + GPS in UTC and I want to show them on my website in local time. What I need is a function that converts lat+long to timezone.

Comment: Okay, so you don't want the time *zone*, you want the local time at a location given its longitude and the UTC time. I would have thought it was good enough just to subtract one hour for every 15° west of the Greenwich Meridian. Anything more accurate would involve checking for national boundaries and daylight saving time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the amount of lookups you need to do and the terms of use, the [Google Time Zone](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/) service looks trivial to use.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;
use JSON::Any;

my ($lat, $long) = (39.6034810,-119.6822510);
my $apikey = 'whatever';
my $time = time();

my $location = JSON::Any->jsonToObj(get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=$lat,$long&timestamp=$time&sensor=false&key=$apikey"));
say $location->{timeZoneId};    # America/Los_Angeles
say $location->{timeZoneName};  # Pacific Standard Time
```

Comment: Thanks. Found that one too, but I would prefer an offline solution. Do you know any?

Comment: Postgres + postgis + continually updating timezone shape files? C/f http://blog.shupp.org/2012/08/12/local-timezone-lookups-by-coordinates-with-postgis/

Comment: Geonames also has some some data with lon/lat + time zones. http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt

Comment: Thanks to all of you. As I'm learning Postgres right now, I will look into Oesor comment once I find the time. For the moment, I'll stick with the online Google API.

Answer (score 0):

I've written [Geo::Location::TimeZoneFinder](https://metacpan.org/pod/Geo::Location::TimeZoneFinder), which uses a shapefile that is published by the [Timezone Boundary Builder](https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder) project. The shapefile can also be used with [Geo::ShapeFile](https://metacpan.org/pod/Geo::ShapeFile).